# Using node's stream to download a video with request and convert it with avconv

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, streaming, avconv

I am trying to get a better understanding of node's streams and want to do something simple :

Download a video from the internet and convert it to mp3.

I'm using the two modules following modules to perform this :

> - request
> - avconv

According to the documentation, both modules supports streams. Here is what I'm trying to do :

```
var avconv = require('avconv');
var request = require('request');
var params = ['-i', 'pipe:0' ,'-vn','-c:a','libmp3lame','-q:a','2','output.mp3'];

var video = request.get([videoURL.mp4])

var convstream = avconv(params);

video.pipe(convstream)
```

Unfortunately, I get this error :

```
node_modules/avconv/avconv.js:142
            source.unpipe(stream);
                   ^
TypeError: Object #<Request> has no method 'unpipe'
```

It seems that the request object has no methode unpipe ! This is very weird because according to the request documentation it seems possible to stream a request to a file, so why not to avconv?

Can somebody point me out to the right direction ? Should I not use streams to perform this task?

Comment: `node -v`? Also versions of the modules.